# Java to C# Trying to learn and understand the differences between the two

Tags: java, c#, arrays, loops

I have taken a couple of Java classes and after doing so learned that C# is very similar and I am attempting to learn by converting simple programs in java to C#. It's been going well so far with simple math problems and printing to the console, but now I am beginning to work with arrays and lists, but I don't seem to be doing something right. My code looks like it should work and the descriptors in Visual Studio 2019 look like everything should run the way I think it does. But it doesn't print out the same meaningful data my Java code does. First Java.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    //Max number method finds the max number of an array list
    public static double largest(ArrayList x){
        double max = (double) x.get(0);
        for (int i =1; i<(double)x.size(); i++){
            if ((double)x.get(i) > max){
                max = (double)x.get(i);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");

        for (int x=0; x<40; x++){
            numbers.add(
                    Double.valueOf(
                            f.format(Math.random()*100 - 1)));
        }

        System.out.println(numbers);
        System.out.println(largest(numbers));
    }
}
```

Now C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Arrays
{
    class Program
    {   
        public static double largest(Array x)
        {
            double max = (double)x.GetValue(0);
            for(int i = 1; i<x.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((double)x.GetValue(i) > max)
                {
                    max = (double)x.GetValue(i);
                }
            }
            return max;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            List<double> numbers = new List<double>();
            for(int x=0; x<40; x++)
            {
                numbers.Add(
                    Math.Round(
                        rand.NextDouble()));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(numbers);
            Console.WriteLine(largest(numbers.ToArray()));

        }
    }
}
```

I understand that the syntax will be different as with any other two languages, but I thought this would work. Self teaching C# so I apologize if this seems overly basic.

Comment: The similarities between Java and C# are more structural and macroscopic than the specific details of how they output lists to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `rand.NextDouble()` in C# returns a number betwenn 0.0 and 1.0. `Math.Round(rand.NextDouble())` will give you either 0 or 1, so by generating 40 random numbers you will get and array full of 0s and 1s.
To make the C# program do what your Java program does, you can use the following code:

```
numbers.Add(
    Math.Round(
        rand.NextDouble() * 100 - 1, 2));
```

Secondly, I guess you see something like

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]

in the output of your program. That's because a `List` in C# doesn't have a nice definition for `ToString` function, while `ArrayList` in Java does.
Actually, if instead of using `ArrayList` you use a standard `double[]` array in Java, you will get a similar 'non-informative' characters printed.

In C#, you can do the following:

```
string.Join(", ", numbers)
```

to make the output similar to Java's `ArrayList`.

Comment: Many thanks! This made everything work the way I thought it would. to low to +1 but thank you. Going to practice this in more complex things now to really see how the two languages differ. It has been very interesting to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in your Main() method, first let's look at the following snippet:

```
numbers.Add(
   Math.Round(
      rand.NextDouble()));
```

`rand.NextDouble()` generates a number between 0-1 with many decimal points.

`Math.Round()` will round a specified number to the nearest whole number and also lets you specify the number of digits to show after the decimal point.

Say we edit this snippet to be:

```
numbers.Add(
   Math.Round(
      rand.NextDouble(), 2));
```

As a result, your List will populate with forty numbers. Each number including two digits after the decimal point.

Next tip, we will look at this line: `Console.WriteLine(numbers)`. This is currently outputing the definition of the variable, something like "Systems.Collections.List"
Instead, if we want to output the values in this collection, then we can parse this List with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (double number in numbers)
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Once these two changes are made, you should see your output display all numbers in your List and an additional last number, being the largest number of the List.

Comment: I'm starting to understand. Very much appreciate the assistance! The "foreach" loop is very insightful. Still learning, so thanks for the tips!